# Can I add TMC stepsticks in parallel with existing A4988?

Tags: motor-controller

I am using from time to time an Ultimaker 2+ Connect, which even if manufactured less than 3 years ago, it uses A4988 as stepper motor controllers, which are old and very noisy. I can hear the motor whining from the floor below with doors open.

I don't want to replace the board and I cannot change its firmware, I would like only to upgrade the X, Y, E motor controllers to [TMC2209](https://www.analog.com/TMC2209/datasheet), which are pin-compatible and backward compatible with A4988 and can be setup via pins, without the need of serial communication. In my case I need to set them to spreadcycle and 1/16 microstepping (before interpolation).

The Ultimaker 2 mainboard ([schematics](http://3dprintingforum.us/viewtopic.php?p=11752#p11757)) uses an ATmega2560 as main microcontroller.

Can I add thin wires for ENABLE, DIR and STEP from the output pins of the existing ATmega2560 to external [stepsticks modules](https://shop.watterott.com/SilentStepStick-TMC2209-Stepper-Motor-Driver)? those lines only carry data, so minimal current is drawn. Moreover, the connection from MCU to A4988 is direct without ANY component in between.

This would potentially result in a fully reversible modification: if I connect the motors to the mainboard, I use the original drivers. If I connect the motors to the external driver boards, I have a quieter printer.

Of course the new drivers require power to run, but the TMC2209 are rated typical 15 mA, max 30 mA each, so it would be 90-120 mA extra load on the 5V regulator of the mainboard, which is rated at 3 A and which therefore should be able to hold: the board has expansion ports so extra load must have been expected.

Would this work or would this damage the existing A4988? they would end up being powered and commanded, but without any load on the motor output.

**Edit**: I just noticed that each EN/STEP/DIR MCU pin is connected also to a test point (TPxxx), so the addition would be quite straightforward.

Still, should I add some extra component? an opamp buffer, an optocoupler? Of course the fewer the better, so I would do it if there is a reason to justify them.

Comment: This might help: [Momentarily running A4988 drivers without a load?](https://reprap.org/forum/read.php?1,886988)

Comment: @Greenonline I found it but that is about disconnecting on the fly. I surely won't do it.

Comment: @Greenonline 1) the inductors are on the motor lines, the signal lines are direct MCU-driver. 2) Optocouplers still suck current from the input pin, and all IO voltages are 5V so I don't see the need. Maybe opamp buffers, to practically cancel any influence of the additional drivers on the MCU output pins? still it makes things more complicated and ATmega usually can provide >8 mA per output pin (I think, old memories) and the drivers are in high impedance mode, taking currents in the uA range... probably not needed

Comment: WRT to the reprap link, I didn't mean the disconnecting whilst powered part, but the fact that the driver will just sit there doing nothing, when the motor is not connected. Similar to boards that have a second extruder port, but the printer itself only has one extruder. The second extruder port doesn't get damaged, in that case (with nothing connected).